# Linear Algebra Orthonormal Sets

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a quick question

If S is an orthonormal set of vectors in Rn, then S is a basis for the subspace it spans. I am not sure if this is true or not based off the definition of orthonormal basis which is a subspace w of Rn is a basis for w that is also an orthogonal set.

Answer (score 2):

Let denote the orthonormal vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_p$ and let $a_1,\ldots, a_p\in\mathbb R$ such that
$$\sum_{k=1}^pa_k v_k=0$$
then

$$0=\left\langle \sum_{k=1}^pa_k v_k/v_i\right\rangle=a_j,\quad \forall j=1,\ldots,p$$
so the vectors are linearly independant.

Answer (score 1):

> If $S$ is an orthonormal set of vectors in $\Bbb R^n$, then, **yes**, $S$ is a basis for the subspace it spans.

Being a basis in the spanned subspace is equivalent to being *linearly independent*. So this claim means exactly that $S$ is then linearly independent. 
(Suppose $\sum_i\lambda_ie_i=0\ $ with some $\,e_i\in S$, then apply scalar multiplication with each $e_j$ to conclude $\lambda_j=0$.)

> **Def.** $S$ is an orthonormal basis for a (sub-)space $W$, if $S$ spans the whole $W$ and length of each element of $S$ is $1$, and any $e,f\in S,\ e\ne f$ satisfies $e\perp f$.